# Why $ \Sigma_{i=1}^{n-1} X^i \leq X^n $ only works for $X = 2$?

Tags: number-theory

Edit : X,N is positive integers.

I tried to bruteforce the cases, it turned that it dont work for many cases, for example X = 3, n= 19.
The referenced bruteforce :

````
#include <iostream>

const long long mod = 1e9 + 7;

long long fastpow(long long a, long long b) {
    if (b == 1) return a;
    if (b == 0) return 1;
    long long x = fastpow(a, b / 2);
    return (b % 2 == 0 ? x * x : (x * x) % mod * a) % mod;
}

signed main() {
    for (long long X = 2; X <= 100; X++) {
        long long cur = 0;
        for (long long N = 0; N < 100; N++) {
            if (cur % mod > fastpow(X, N) % mod) {
                std::cout << X << ' ' << N << std::endl;
            }
            cur += fastpow(X, N);
            cur %= mod;
        }
    }
}


```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: With the left side of the equation, do you mean the geometric sum? If yes, then there's a pretty simple form for it.

Comment: Maybe try to use the geometric sum formula $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} q^i = \frac{1-q^{n}}{1-q}$

Comment: @MattiP. no it's not geometric sum, X, N is integers

Comment: @JMP You are incorrct. linkja's remark is specifically about *finite* sums, for which the statement is true.

Comment: @linkja X, N is integers.

Comment: For $n=19$ and $X=3$ I get the sum $581130732$ and 3 to the power of 19 to be $1162261467$ so it seems fine but maybe I'm missing something but I would expect this to be true for any $X$.

Comment: The formula @linkja gives is also valid for $q=X$ an integer.

Comment: It seems to me clear that using schoolboy mathematics the inequality is true for all $X\ge 2$, since $X^n\ge 2X^{n-1}\ge 2X^{n-1} -1$. I have no idea what all the crazy code is about so I can't give an answer.

Comment: Your code is wrong. It works for `fastpow(3,18)` but fails `fastpow(3,19)`. That's why you reach a wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometric sum formula, as others have mentioned, also works for integers.

So we can conclude (for $X>1$, since $X=1$ is obvious)
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X^i = \frac{1-X^n}{1- X} - 1$$
Now you can verify that
\begin{align}\frac{1-X^n}{1- X} - 1 \leq X^{n} \iff  &1-X^n - 1 + X \geq X^n - X^{n+1}\\
\iff & X^{n+1}-2X^n+ X \geq 0  \\ \iff & X^n \geq 2X^{n-1} - 1\end{align}
The last inequality clearly holds for $X > 2$ since then $X^n> 2X^{n-1} > 2X^{n-1} -1$

Now for $X = 2$ one can check directly that your inequality holds.